# Sql Server Stored Procedure repeated operations on a temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which generates many reports, all the reports have a total column and percentage computation column. So basically the last row of temp table is total column. Following is my code.

```
declare @Yr1Tot int, @Yr2Tot int
create table #SrcCnt(id int identity(1,1), Src varchar(100), Yr1Cnt money, Yr1Per varchar(20), Yr2Cnt money, Yr2Per varchar(20))

-- Report 1 generation
insert into #SrcCnt(Src, Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt)
select 'Rep1-1', 10 , 20 union
select 'Rep1-2', 1 , 2 union
select 'Rep1-3', 15 , 25 union
select 'Rep1-4', 8 , 87 union
select 'Rep1-5', 4 , 5 union
select 'Rep1-6', 7 , 9 union
select 'Rep1-7', 11 , 30 

-- Following block is repeated for all reports
insert into #SrcCnt(Src, Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt)
select 'Total', sum(Yr1Cnt), sum(Yr2Cnt) from #SrcCnt

select @Yr1Tot = Yr1Cnt, @Yr2Tot = Yr2Cnt from #SrcCnt where Src = 'Total'

update #SrcCnt set Yr1Per = (Yr1Cnt * 100)/@Yr1Tot 
update #SrcCnt set Yr2Per = (Yr2Cnt * 100)/@Yr2Tot

update #SrcCnt set Yr1Per = case when Yr1Per = '0' then null else Yr1Per + '%' end 
update #SrcCnt set Yr2Per = case when Yr2Per = '0' then null else Yr2Per + '%' end 

select * from #SrcCnt order by id
 -- End of repetative code



-- Report 2 generation

delete from #SrcCnt

insert into #SrcCnt(Src, Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt)
select 'Rep2-1', 10 , 20 union
select 'Rep2-2', 1 , 2 union
select 'Rep2-3', 15 , 25 union
select 'Rep2-4', 8 , 87 union
select 'Rep2-5', 4 , 5 union
select 'Rep2-6', 7 , 9 union
select 'Rep2-7', 11 , 30 


insert into #SrcCnt(Src, Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt)
select 'Total', sum(Yr1Cnt), sum(Yr2Cnt) from #SrcCnt


select @Yr1Tot = Yr1Cnt, @Yr2Tot = Yr2Cnt from #SrcCnt where Src = 'Total'

update #SrcCnt set Yr1Per = (Yr1Cnt * 100)/@Yr1Tot 
update #SrcCnt set Yr2Per = (Yr2Cnt * 100)/@Yr2Tot

update #SrcCnt set Yr1Per = case when Yr1Per = '0' then null else Yr1Per + '%' end 
update #SrcCnt set Yr2Per = case when Yr2Per = '0' then null else Yr2Per + '%' end 

select * from #SrcCnt order by id


-- Report 3 generation

delete from #SrcCnt

insert into #SrcCnt(Src, Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt)
select 'Rep3-1', 10 , 20 union
select 'Rep3-2', 1 , 2 union
select 'Rep3-3', 15 , 25 union
select 'Rep3-4', 8 , 87 union
select 'Rep3-5', 4 , 5 union
select 'Rep3-6', 7 , 9 union
select 'Rep3-7', 11 , 30 


insert into #SrcCnt(Src, Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt)
select 'Total', sum(Yr1Cnt), sum(Yr2Cnt) from #SrcCnt


select @Yr1Tot = Yr1Cnt, @Yr2Tot = Yr2Cnt from #SrcCnt where Src = 'Total'

update #SrcCnt set Yr1Per = (Yr1Cnt * 100)/@Yr1Tot 
update #SrcCnt set Yr2Per = (Yr2Cnt * 100)/@Yr2Tot

update #SrcCnt set Yr1Per = case when Yr1Per = '0' then null else Yr1Per + '%' end 
update #SrcCnt set Yr2Per = case when Yr2Per = '0' then null else Yr2Per + '%' end 

select * from #SrcCnt order by id
```

So, now there are atleast 30 reports in my stored procedure, all of them should be generated on calling this SP, that means I need to repeat total generation and percentage generation code several times as shown in above code. Is there a better approach than creating a UserDefined DataTable/copying and pasting it several times.

Comment: What is a "report" here? Can you show code for at least two "reports"?

Comment: The column Src can have different values depending on the report, for example it can be Years of Experience or Grades or Age, etc., Will edit question and post output for ref.

Comment: Yes Yes, it has data, each report has different data, only the last adding total column and percentage column are same for all reports.

Comment: Is that output for 1 report or for 6 reports?

Comment: It's for one report

Comment: Again, how would your code and data look like for **more than one report**? How does your SP understand that there are **more than one reports** required?

Comment: Modified question completey, you can copy paste and execute the code.

Comment: A better design might be to include a reportid and line number in the table.

Comment: How does that solve code repetition problem? I need to generate all the reports on calling this SP.

Comment: So there are not source tables, all the data is predefined within this SP, right? And the number of "reports" is predefined as well, right? This SP has no arguments and the client-side is always ready for any number of "reports", right?

Comment: There are source tables and data is not pre-defined, only the output format for all the reports is same. No.of reports is predefined, no arguments. Client side is ready for any no.of reports.

Comment: Extract each report to separate SP, execute "report set(s)" and maintain their output by dynamic sql or keep copy-pasting. Note, all of these "totals" (sum, %) can be computed on client-side as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do is to wrap  your calculation of percentage code in a User Defined Function (udf) that returns a Table. Pass a table type variable to the udf , do the calculation in the udf and call the udf to get a result set as table data rows. However to pass a table to udf you need to create a User Define Table Type.

Here is the example codes :

```
/ * Create User Defined Table Type */
CREATE TYPE x2_SrcCntTableType AS TABLE (
   id int identity(1,1)
   ,Src varchar(100)
   , Yr1Cnt money
   , Yr1Per varchar(20)
   , Yr2Cnt money
   , Yr2Per varchar(20))
GO

/* Create User Defined Table-Valued Function */
        CREATE FUNCTION x2_getSrcCntPercentage
    (
        @srcCntOrig x2_SrcCntTableType READONLY -- this table should always readonly

    )
    RETURNS 
    @SrcCnt TABLE 
    (
        -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
          id int identity(1,1)
        , Src varchar(100)
        , Yr1Cnt money
        , Yr1Per varchar(20)
        , Yr2Cnt money
        , Yr2Per varchar(20)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- Fill the table variable with the rows for your result set
        -- copy data from @srcCntOrig to @SrcCnt table
        -- because srcCntOrig is readonly, so do the udates on table SrcCnt 

         insert into  @SrcCnt(Src, Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt)
         SELECT   Src, Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt FROM @srcCntOrig

         insert into @SrcCnt(Src, Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt)
         select 'Total', sum(Yr1Cnt), sum(Yr2Cnt) from @SrcCnt



        declare @Yr1Tot int, @Yr2Tot int

        select @Yr1Tot = Yr1Cnt, @Yr2Tot = Yr2Cnt from @SrcCnt where Src = 'Total'

        update @SrcCnt set Yr1Per = (Yr1Cnt * 100)/@Yr1Tot 
        update @SrcCnt set Yr2Per = (Yr2Cnt * 100)/@Yr2Tot

        update @SrcCnt set Yr1Per = case when Yr1Per = '0' then null else Yr1Per + '%' end 
        update @SrcCnt set Yr2Per = case when Yr2Per = '0' then null else Yr2Per + '%' end 

        -- select * from #SrcCnt order by id

        RETURN 
    END
GO
```

And then you can call the udf from a query/stored procedure :

```
    declare @SrcCnt x2_SrcCntTableType

    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt) VALUES ('0 - 5 Years',143,43)
    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt) VALUES ('6 - 10 Years',28,17)
    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt) VALUES ('11 - 15 Years',9,5)
    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt) VALUES ('16 - 20 Years',7,2)
    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt) VALUES ('21 - 30 Years',11,3)
    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt) VALUES ('> 30  Years',91,55)

    SELECT * from dbo.x2_getSrcCntPercentage(@SrcCnt)
```

Result :

```
id  Src             Yr1Cnt   Yr1Per Yr2Cnt  Yr2Per
---------------------------------------------------
1   0 - 5 Years     143,00   49.48%  43,00   34.40%
2   6 - 10 Years     28,00    9.69%  17,00   13.60%
3   11 - 15 Years     9,00    3.11%   5,00    4.00%
4   16 - 20 Years     7,00    2.42%   2,00    1.60%
5   21 - 30 Years    11,00    3.81%   3,00    2.40%
6   > 30  Years      91,00   31.49%  55,00   44.00%
7   Total           289,00  100.00% 125,00  100.00%
```

*(Updated)* Ok. There is another option without using UDF. However you need to have the Total of Yr1Cnt and Yr2Cnt available before you make insertions to @SrcCnt table. The trick is to use COMPUTED COLUMN.

Here is the partial code for your stored procedure :

```
declare @SrcCnt TABLE 
    (
        -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
          id int identity(1,1)
        , Src varchar(100)
        , Yr1Cnt money
        , Yr1Per AS Cast(Cast((Yr1Cnt/TotYr1Cnt)*100 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(10)) + ' %' -- COMPUTED COLUMN
        , Yr2Cnt money
        , Yr2Per AS Cast(Cast((Yr2Cnt/TotYr2Cnt)*100 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(10)) + ' %' -- COMPUTED COLUMN
        , TotYr1Cnt money
        , TotYr2Cnt money
    )

    declare @TotYr1Cnt money = 289 -- maybe calculated elsewhere but prior to inserting data to @SrcCnt
    declare @TotYr2Cnt money = 125

    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt,TotYr1Cnt,TotYr2Cnt) VALUES ('0 - 5 Years',143,43,@TotYr1Cnt,@TotYr2Cnt)
    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt,TotYr1Cnt,TotYr2Cnt) VALUES ('6 - 10 Years',28,17,@TotYr1Cnt,@TotYr2Cnt)
    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt,TotYr1Cnt,TotYr2Cnt) VALUES ('11 - 15 Years',9,5,@TotYr1Cnt,@TotYr2Cnt)
    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt,TotYr1Cnt,TotYr2Cnt) VALUES ('16 - 20 Years',7,2,@TotYr1Cnt,@TotYr2Cnt)
    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt,TotYr1Cnt,TotYr2Cnt) VALUES ('21 - 30 Years',11,3,@TotYr1Cnt,@TotYr2Cnt)
    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt,TotYr1Cnt,TotYr2Cnt) VALUES ('> 30  Years',91,55,@TotYr1Cnt,@TotYr2Cnt)

    INSERT INTO @SrcCnt(Src,Yr1Cnt,Yr2Cnt,TotYr1Cnt,TotYr2Cnt) VALUES ('Total',@TotYr1Cnt,@TotYr2Cnt,@TotYr1Cnt,@TotYr2Cnt)

     SELECT * FROM @SrcCnt
```

Comment: I wanted to do this, but then you know maintenance cost of User Defined Table types is very high, that is why in my question, I said other than user defined table types. If there is no other solution, will use this. Thank you soo much.

Comment: I cannot think of other solution besides copy and paste the calculation code into your stored procedure. Yes there is a performance penalty in using udf table type, but your code will be modular and easy to maintain,  and looking at your codes I think the penalty should be tolerable, because the table only has few rows to process.

Comment: Ok. Actually there is another option to your problem.  However you need to have the total of Yr1Cnt and Yr2Cnt available, before you make insertion to the #SrcCnt table.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check it out, if that fulfills your requirement.